# How to handle python inheritance properly

Tags: python, inheritance

I've read the python documentation, but I still have questions about inheritance.

- It seems in older versions of python you could pass arguments to super, but no longer. What if SuperClass does some sort of setup using its arguments?
- If inheriting from object, should I call super? As far as I can tell, it doesn't make a functional difference.
- Is this handled differently in python 2.7 vs. 3.x?

Is this how inheritance is supposed to be handled?

```
class SuperClass(object):
    def __init__(self, super_argument):
        super(object, self).__init__()
        self.super_argument = super_argument
        self.foo()

class ChildClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self, super_argument):
        self.super_argument = super_argument
        super(SuperClass, self).__init__()
```

If so, does that make this an unworkable design for a class which might be inherited?

```
class SuperClass(object):
    def __init__(self, super_argument):
        super(object, self).__init__()
        self.foo(super_argument) # Argument passed instead without saving in self
```

Comment: *"pass arguments to super"* - do you mean `super(here).method()` or `super().method(here)`?

Comment: `super(SuperClass, self).__init__(super_argument)` or `super(SuperClass, self, super_argument).__init__()`

Comment: That's slightly unhelpful, because what you've done there is include both sets of arguments, rather than specify *which ones you're asking about!* You can leave out `SuperClass, self` if you're writing *only* for 3.x, but `super_argument` is still used as before.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not exactly sure where the confusion is. When I instantiate SuperClass on its own, i can pass it arguments which go to init. It doesn't seem like I can do that when instantiating it as a super class.

Comment: Could you show the failing case, with the full traceback? I've had a stab at answering, but I suspect we're still talking at cross purposes, and a [mcve] might really clear things up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems in older versions of python you could pass arguments to
>   super, but no longer. What if SuperClass does some sort of setup using
>   its arguments?

I think you've misunderstood which set of arguments you can leave out in 3.x. In Python 2.x, you *needed* to pass arguments to `super` to get the correctly-bound method:

```
class MyClass(...):

    def __init__(self, ...):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(...)
            # ^ these arguments       ^ not these
```

In 3.x, you aren't *required* to supply those arguments, you can just call `super().method(...)`, but it will accept them just fine.

This is the same as the behaviour with inheriting `object` - you must do it to get a new-style class in 2.x, but 3.x will create a new-style class whether or not you explicitly inherit `object`.

---

Either way, **you *can* pass arguments to the method on `super`**. So if you're writing only for 3.x, you could do something like:

```
class MyClass(SuperClass):

    def __init__(self, super_arg, my_arg):
        super().__init__(super_arg)
            # ^ don't need these
                       # ^ still need these
        self.my_arg = my_arg
```

---

> If inheriting from object, should I call super?

Yes, because you may be involved in multiple inheritance. Compare:

```
>>> class SuperClass1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("SuperClass1.__init__")


>>> class SuperClass2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("SuperClass2.__init__")


>>> class MyClass(SuperClass1, SuperClass2):
    def __init__(self):
        print("MyClass.__init__")
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()


>>> MyClass()
MyClass.__init__
SuperClass1.__init__
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x02D0CC50>
```

with:

```
>>> class SuperClass1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("SuperClass1.__init__")
        super(SuperClass1, self).__init__()


>>> class SuperClass2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("SuperClass2.__init__")
        super(SuperClass2, self).__init__()


>>> class MyClass(SuperClass1, SuperClass2):
    def __init__(self):
        print("MyClass.__init__")
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()


>>> MyClass()
MyClass.__init__
SuperClass1.__init__
SuperClass2.__init__
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x02BCDC10>
```

In the former, because `SuperClass1` doesn't call `super`, `SuperClass2.__init__` never gets reached.

---

> Is this handled differently in python 2.7 vs. 3.x?

Hopefully this is now clear - you need to be more explicit in 2.x (or if you're writing code that should work in both versions) but otherwise the functionality is identical, and you should call `super` at all levels in both.

Comment: What does the first SuperClass2 do? Doesn't the second overwrite the first?

Comment: In your second example (the one after 'with:'), it seems like you define SuperClass2 twice. Was that a typo?

Comment: Okay, then thank you. I now understand perfectly. I was mostly confused about the differences between the old and new style of classes. Slightly off topic, but to make sure I'm understanding correctly, during multiple class inheritance, the class to the left instantiates the one to the right? Does that mean the ones further down the arguments list will overwrite methods of earlier ones if they have the same name?

Comment: @JamesFargotson no, the left-most inherited class is the **first** in the method resolution order (see the `__mro__` attribute, and note that `SuperClass1.__init__` is called *before* `SuperClass2.__init__`), so the opposite happens - its method implementations shadow any implementations on classes to the right of it.